# Internal Salesforce Error: 385931901-33596 (922176288) (922176288)

Tags: gack

Noticed strange error when running unit tests, not able to figure out why is this happening? It fails only in one org with this error

```
Internal Salesforce Error: 385931901-33596 (922176288) (922176288)
```

The code of the failing test method

```
static testMethod void testUpdateOLS() {
    PermissionSet ps = new PermissionSet(Name='Test', Label='Test');
    insert ps;
    ...
    Test.startTest();
        ...
    Test.stopTest();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My original assumption was wrong, there is some error in the unit tests when permission set with the same name is inserted in multiple methods of one test class.

There are several workarounds for that:

1. Move permission set insert to the @testSetup method.
2. Use different permission set names in different test methods.
3. Move method to a different test class.

I have opened a case with Salesforce Support and they opened [public known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V0000029LUzQAM) which seems to describe a little different issue outside the unit tests.